# How to find last occurrence of pattern and print all lines following the last occurance

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which contains multiple occurrences of pattern *"===="*. These patterns are followed by texts. I'd like to search for the last occurrence of the *"===="* pattern and print all the lines after the pattern. Any ideas on how to do it in bash? Combination of `grep`, `awk`, `sed` or `tail`, etc..?

Sample file:

```
====

First run of script

End of first Script

====

2nd run of script

End of 2nd script

====

3rd run of script

End of 3rd script
```

Output of the command should look like below.

```
3rd run of script

End of 3rd script
```

Comment: Thank you @l0b0 for posting the link. Sorry for the duplicate question. I had done many searches for a possible solution and the link you provided matches my exact needs.

Comment: No problem at all; cross-site duplicates aren't a thing, and a question being duplicate doesn't mean it's bad.

Comment: Welcome , You can vote up or accept the answer which solve your problem instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 7):

Same concept as agc's answer, but doesn't require you to guess how many lines there might be:

with GNU sed

```
tac file | sed '/====/Q' | tac
```

or awk

```
tac file | awk '/====/ {exit} 1' | tac
```

The idea of the double `tac` is to invert the question: How to print all lines ***preceding*** the ***first*** occurrence of pattern. That is a much simpler problem.

Answer (score 5):

Software tools method, more efficient for big files since it only reads the end of the file, then stops when it finds the last match:

```
tac sample.txt | grep -F -m1 -B 999999 '====' | head -n -1 | tac
```

Note: increase or reduce `999999` as needed, just so it's longer than any possible match.  This code would work best if it's known in advance that the last match is known to be near the end of a large file.  See also [*Glenn Jackman*'s answer with variants for `awk` and `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467850/165517) which avoid the need for `999999`.  For systems with very low resources, `grep` is more efficient than `awk` or `sed`.

To avoid guessing, some added `stat` ugliness would work:

```
f=sample.txt; tac "$f" | grep -F -m1 -B $(stat -c '%s' "$f") '====' |
head -n -1 | tac
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on [SO duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30958584/96588):

```
$ sed -n '/====/h;//!H;$!d;x;//p' sample.txt 
====

3rd run of script

End of 3rd script

Output of the command should look like below.

3rd run of script

End of 3rd script
```

I started writing an explanation, but I don't actually understand some of the commands so I'll just refer to `info sed`.

Comment: (Let's see if I got this right) `/====/h` sets the hold buffer to the current line if it matches `====`; `//!H` adds it to the hold buffer if it _doesn't_ match `====`. Those combine to clear the hold on a `====` and to store any lines in there. Then `$!d` deletes the current line (it's already stored in the hold) and jumps to the next, unless this was the last line. The `x` and `p` only run on the last line: `x` loads the hold buffer to the active buffer, and `//p` prints it if it contains a `====`. (The `//` pattern means to use the previous pattern, so it's just a shorthand for `/====/`.)

Comment: The final condition on the `p` means that if `====` isn't seen, this won't print anything. But this also will print the `====` line itself.

Answer (score 2):

In `awk`, something like this:

```
awk '/====/ { t = ""; next } { t = t $0 "\n"; } END { printf "%s", t; }' < sample.txt
```

It stores the input lines in `t`, and clears `t` when it sees `====`. What ever is in there is printed at the end.

Note that

- The `====` doesn't have to be on a line of its own (strictly speaking, you didn't say it should be). If you want to only recognize it when it's the only thing on a line, use `/^====$/` instead.
- This prints the whole input if `====` is not seen. Checking that there is at least one needs an extra condition, see below.
- Your sample output is missing the first empty line after the `====`, but that might be just the post formatting. If you do want to remove it, add a pipe to `sed 1d`.

Another version that only starts storing input after the `====` separator is seen, effectively producing an empty output if the input doesn't contain the separator:

```
awk '/====/ { any = 1; t = ""; next } any { t = t $0 "\n"; } END { printf "%s", t; }' < sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

save the text in `file.txt` and run this command:

```
awk 'p; /====/ $p' file.txt | tail -3
```

output:

```
3rd run of script

End of 3rd script
```

Comment: Your `awk` command doesn't do anything... You may as well run only `tail -3` (which is obsolete - you should use `tail` with `-n`). Either way, this only works with the OP input sample, that is it only prints the last 3 lines, _regardless_. I guess the 3 people who mechanically upvoted here don't care about that.

Comment: With `p` unset, the first `p` is a falsy condition, and doesn't do anything. The second is the same as `/====/ $0` when `p` gets coerced to an integer, but what in the world is the concatenation of a regex and a field (or string) supposed to be? It does seem to act like a true condition, though, so it looks like that's the same as running `awk 1`. Or `cat`.