# sed script to print n lines after the last occurence of a match

Tags: text-processing, sed

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467805/how-to-find-last-occurrence-of-pattern-and-print-all-lines-following-the-last-oc) is a link to print all lines following the last occurrence of a match.

However, I only want to print two lines after the last occurence of a match.  How would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to pipe the output to something like " ... | head -n 2" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed` and assuming you want the two lines *after* the last match of `pattern` (and additionally assuming that each line matching `pattern` is at least two lines apart from any other matching line):

```
$ cat file
a
b       pattern
c       the 1st
d       the 2nd
e       the 3rd
1
2
3       pattern
4       the first
5       the second
6       the third
7
```

```
$ sed -n -e '/pattern/ { n; N; h; }' -e '$ { g; /./p; }' file
4       the first
5       the second
```

The `sed` command reads the next line in with `n` whenever `pattern` is matched.  The line after that is appended to the buffer with `N` and both lines are copied over to the hold space with `h` (over-writing whatever used to be stored there).

When we reach the last line, we get the hold space, which now contains the most recent two lines after the line matching `pattern`, or it is empty if no `pattern` was matched.  If the buffer isn't empty, it is outputted.

To get the *three* lines after the line that matches `pattern`, use `n; N; N; h;` in place of `n; N; h;`.

Getting the three lines after the line matching `pattern` (now assuming matching lines are at least three lines apart):

```
$ sed -n -e '/pattern/ { n; N; N; h; }' -e '$ { g; /./p; }' file
4       the first
5       the second
6       the third
```

---

Removing the need for lines matching `pattern` to be far apart, we need to check whether any of the "lines after" matches `pattern` as we read them, and if one does, restart from there.

```bsh
sed -n -e ':a' -e '/pattern/ { n; /pattern/ba; N; /pattern/ba; h; }' -e '$ { x; /./p; }' file
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I was looking for.  What if I want to get the text between last pattern and the empty line (i.e. the first\n the second \n the third\n)?

Comment: @asub I believe this is exactly what I show in my second `sed` command example in the answer already. And oh, the lines aren't empty.

Comment: In the second example, you know that there are three lines before a new line.  But if you don't know how many lines there are between pattern and an empty line? I.e. how do you loop until you meet an empty line?

Comment: @asub There are no empty lines. The last line of my example data has a `7` at the start of it.  The `sed` code explicitly looks for 3 lines after the match, it does not search for an empty line.  If you wanted to search for an empty line, then this and the other answers here are wrong, because that was not the issue in the question.

Comment: You are right.  I was asking yet another question :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' '?pattern?+1, ?pattern?+2 p' | ed -s file
```

This sends one command to `ed` on stdin; the `-s` flag inhibits the byte-count as output when the file is read. The command breaks down like this:

- `... , ... p` -- print the lines in the given (... , ...) address range
- `?pattern?+1` -- search backwards for `pattern` then add one
- `?pattern?+2` -- search backwards for `pattern` then add two

The current defaults to the last line of the file, so these searches find the last occurrence of `pattern` in the file. The offsets then select the two lines that follow.

Comment: As does `printf '%s\n' '?pattern?+1, ??+2 p' | ed -s file`.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU `grep` and `tail` and [αғsнιη's example file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647332/22222):

```
$ cat file
====
1
2
3
4
====
11
22
33
====
111
222
333
444
====
1111
2222
3333

$ grep  -A2 "====" file  | tail -n2
1111
2222
```

The `-A2` tells `grep` to print the matching line (in this case, we are searching for `====`) and the two lines after it. Then, `tail -n2` prints only the last two lines.

If your file is very large, you could make it faster by reading from the end of the file with `tac` and reversing the logic:

```
$ tac file | grep -m1 -B2 "====" | tac |tail -n2
1111
2222
```

Answer (score 3):

Using *awk*:

```
awk '/====/{ buf=""; c=0; found=1; next }
    ++c<=2 { buf=(buf==""?"":buf ORS) $0 }
END{ if(c>=2 && found)print buf }' infile
```

Input:

```
====
1
2
3
4
====
11
22
33
====
111
222
333
444
====
1111
2222
3333
```

Output:

```
1111
2222
```

Answer (score 1):

**GNU sed** in extended regex mode `-E`
Change the shell variable to the number of lines you want to see.

```
n=2
sed -Ee '
  /\n/q
  /pattern/{
    :loop
      $d;N
    /(.*\n){'"$n"'}/!bloop
    x
  }
  $!d;x
  /\n.*\n/D
  s/.*\n//p;d
' file
```

- After the pattern line is found setup a loop to accumulate lines in pattern space.
- stop when the n-th line after pattern line is seen (not counting the pattern line).
- store these n+1 lines in the hold and if not reached eof, restart the search for next possible occurrence of pattern.
- Finally at eof, retrieve the hold space data and strip off the first line from it (the pattern line).

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

`awk '{ arr[NR]=$0; if ($0 ~ /====/) line=NR}END{if (line) for(i=line+1;i<=line+2;i++) print arr[i]}' file`

`arr[NR] = $0` creates an array containing all records of file.

Then `if ($0 ~ /====/) line=NR}` finds last record of file containing that pattern. This expression can be written as `if (/====/) line=NR`.

And at last for loop prints lines after last match. If three lines are required then size of loop can be changed to 3 with `i<=line+3`.

`if (line)` will prevent printing of first two lines of file if no pattern is found.

But what if pattern is found on last record of the file. The above solution would print empty lines.

The following would work only if the file has at least two records after record containing that pattern.

`awk '{ arr[NR]=$0; if ($0 ~ /====/) line=NR}END{if (line) for(i=line+1;i<=line+2;i++){ if (i < (NR -1)) print arr[i]}}' file`

The following should work if file has one *or* two records after that pattern. This won't give anything if pattern is found on last line.

`awk '{ arr[NR]=$0; if ($0 ~ /====/) line=NR}END{if (line) for(i=line+1;i<=line+2;i++){ if (i <= NR) print arr[i]}}' file`